# How to increase and decrease text size in web page?

Tags: php, jquery, css, text-size

How do I increase and decrease text size on a web page using PHP, CSS, or JQuery?

Comment: Using jQuery: `$("#divs_id_that_I_want_to_increase_text").css("font-size", "22px");`

Comment: I assume this question is about accessibility, and increasing the text size globally across all elements, and with the site remembering across different pages.  Hence the answers below are pretty useless....

Comment: @ck so I assume you have an answer which uses php?

Comment: nope, I've never done this.  I just use the zoom buttons on my keyboard....

Answer (score 3):

You can increase text size on the whole page (for all elements that inherit text size from the 'body') with:

```
function setFontSize(size) {
    $('body').css('font-size', '' + size + 'px');
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j3mkW/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Set text-size on the text container (a p, a div, a span, ...).

```
<p style='font-size:120%'>
```

Comment: `text-size`? is this a new css style?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `font-size` CSS property

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @pinkalvansia that is the page of the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C). Pretty sure it will not change ;)